# First Responder not setting focus on uitextfield

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, first-responder

I am trying to set the focus of a uitextfield. Using this code

```
[_partNoTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

When I run the code, the keyboard goes away and the text field is not in focus. I need it to focus on _partNoTextField after it runs my IBAction checkpartno. On the textfield I have setup Did end on exit to call my checkpartno ibaction so when a user hits return it runs it. How can I get the focus to go back to the _partNoTextField ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the "did end on exit" selector but instead set a delegate from the text field back to your controller and then:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // i.e. run your IBAction when clicking on return key
    //
    // here I am assuming your checkparno action lives in the 
    // same object as your delegate
    [self checkpartno: textField]; 
    return NO; // returning NO means the keyboard stays up
}
```